# How to draw a gradient rectangle in PHP?

Tags: php, drawing, gd

I want to draw a double gradient like this [image: gradient] in PHP (in different colors).

**Edit:** Ended up modifying one of the provided gradient functions in the answers to simply draw the double gradient.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

create gradients in PHP using the normal GD Image functions. The function uses HTML Hex Codes for the color values and then converts them over to an array that has the RGB values.

```
function image_gradientrect($img,$x,$y,$x1,$y1,$start,$end) {
   if($x > $x1 || $y > $y1) {
      return false;
   }
   $s = array(
      hexdec(substr($start,0,2)),
      hexdec(substr($start,2,2)),
      hexdec(substr($start,4,2))
   );
   $e = array(
      hexdec(substr($end,0,2)),
      hexdec(substr($end,2,2)),
      hexdec(substr($end,4,2))
   );
   $steps = $y1 - $y;
   for($i = 0; $i < $steps; $i++) {
      $r = $s[0] - ((($s[0]-$e[0])/$steps)*$i);
      $g = $s[1] - ((($s[1]-$e[1])/$steps)*$i);
      $b = $s[2] - ((($s[2]-$e[2])/$steps)*$i);
      $color = imagecolorallocate($img,$r,$g,$b);
      imagefilledrectangle($img,$x,$y+$i,$x1,$y+$i+1,$color);
   }
   return true;
}


$imgWidth = 300;
$imgHeight = 150;
$img = imagecreatetruecolor($imgWidth,$imgHeight);

image_gradientrect($img,0,0,$imgWidth,$imgHeight,'ff0000','0000ff');
/* Show In Browser as Image */
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($img);

/* Save as a File */
imagepng($img,'save.png');

/* Some Cleanup */
imagedestroy($img);
```

Just change the height & widht and color in above code and it will generate the rectangle image.

Answer (score 3):

This source ref. to PHP documentation Page by Christoper Kramer.
Try it. There is no "build in" function in PHP to draw this.

```
function gradient($w=100, $h=100, $c=array('#FFFFFF','#FF0000','#00FF00','#0000FF'), $hex=true) {

    /*
    Generates a gradient image

    Author: Christopher Kramer

    Parameters:
    w: width in px
    h: height in px
    c: color-array with 4 elements:
        $c[0]:   top left color
        $c[1]:   top right color
        $c[2]:   bottom left color
        $c[3]:   bottom right color

    if $hex is true (default), colors are hex-strings like '#FFFFFF' (NOT '#FFF')
    if $hex is false, a color is an array of 3 elements which are the rgb-values, e.g.:
    $c[0]=array(0,255,255);

    */

    $im=imagecreatetruecolor($w,$h);

    if($hex) {  // convert hex-values to rgb
        for($i=0;$i<=3;$i++) {
            $c[$i]=hex2rgb($c[$i]);
        }
    }

    $rgb=$c[0]; // start with top left color
    for($x=0;$x<=$w;$x++) { // loop columns
        for($y=0;$y<=$h;$y++) { // loop rows
            // set pixel color 
            $col=imagecolorallocate($im,$rgb[0],$rgb[1],$rgb[2]);
            imagesetpixel($im,$x-1,$y-1,$col);
            // calculate new color  
            for($i=0;$i<=2;$i++) {
                $rgb[$i]=
                    $c[0][$i]*(($w-$x)*($h-$y)/($w*$h)) +
                    $c[1][$i]*($x     *($h-$y)/($w*$h)) +
                    $c[2][$i]*(($w-$x)*$y     /($w*$h)) +
                    $c[3][$i]*($x     *$y     /($w*$h));
            }
        }
    }
    return $im;
}

function hex2rgb($hex)
{
    $rgb[0]=hexdec(substr($hex,1,2));
    $rgb[1]=hexdec(substr($hex,3,2));
    $rgb[2]=hexdec(substr($hex,5,2));
    return($rgb);
}

// usage example

$image=gradient(300, 300, array('#000000', '#FFFFFF', '#FF0000', '#0000FF'));

header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);
```

Answer (score -3):

```
bool imagefilledrectangle ( resource $image , int $x1 , int $y1 , int $x2 , int $y2 , int $color )
```

Comment: This will hardly draw a gradient.

Answer (score -4):

If I understand it correctly you want to draw a gradient on a webpage. PHP is a server side script and nothing to do with Presetation. So HTML and JS can help you. Create a Canvas and then

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
```

**Javascript**

```
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");

var grd=ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,170,0);
grd.addColorStop(0,"black");
grd.addColorStop(1,"white");

ctx.fillStyle=grd;
ctx.fillRect(20,20,150,100);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I really wanted to draw an image with PHP.